# Lambda Expression goes to syntax

Tags: c#

I'm having difficulty understand the following Lambda expression. If I'm not mistaken the => operator mean goes to.

I have this method that generate pdf from xps. Does this method mean run GeneratePdf method then do whatever with the result variable pdf?

```
public void GenerateCurrentPdf(FooResponse response)
{
    if (response.Success)
    {
        GeneratePdf(pdf =>
        {
            var attachInfo = new AttachmentInformation
            {
                AttachmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                AttachmentNote = "New Version",
                FileName = pdf.FileName,
                ImageByte = pdf.FileBytes
            };

            try
            {
                /// do something here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ///log error
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The GeneratePdf method confused me even more since it's not passing any parameters from the calling method. I look up Action in MSDN, it said "Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a value." but the end of GeneratePdf is calling GeneratePdf method again.

```
public void GeneratePdf(Action<FileAttachment> onComplete)
{
    string xpsPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + Id + ".xps";

    SaveAsXps(xpsPath, () =>
    {
        string pdfPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + Id + ".pdf";
        string registrationCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("NiXPS:RegistrationCode");
        Converter.Initialize(registrationCode);
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        Converter.XpsToPdf(new MemoryStream(FileToByteArray(xpsPath)), outStream);
        File.Delete(xpsPath);
        byte[] bytes = outStream.ToArray();        
        var attachment = new FileAttachment
        {
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            FileBytes = bytes,
            FileName = fooId + ".pdf"          
        };
        onComplete(attachment);
    });
}
```

Added SaveAsXps method

```
private void SaveAsXps(string path, Action onComplete)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        (Action)
            delegate
            {
                Package package = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Create);
                var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum);
                var xpsSm = new XpsSerializationManager(new XpsPackagingPolicy(xpsDoc), false);
                string formulaFooter = Title;
                var finalDocument = new HeaderFooterDocumentPrint(DocumentPrint, formulaFooter);
                finalDocument.ComputePageCount();
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    (Action) delegate 
                    {
                        xpsSm.SaveAsXaml(finalDocument);
                        package.Close();
                        onComplete();
                    }, DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, null);
            }, DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete syntax is (list of parameters) => { method body }

If you have only one parameter you can discard the ().

If you just want to return a value you can discard {} and just write the result value.

The following are equivalent:

```
a => a + 1
(a) => a + 1
(a) => { return a+1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a Lambda that represents an `Action<FileAttachment>`

```
pdf =>
    {
        // ...
    }
```

I would state in English that it translates to the compiler to pass an argument named `pdf` into the following delegate (it can infer the type).

It's roughly the same as:

```
private void MyCallback(FileAttachment pdf)
{
    // ...
}
```

`Action<T>` is defined as `public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);`. Put plainly it is essentially a handy built-in delegate definition for a void function accepting a generic argument of whatever type you tell it.

Answer (score 0):

`=>` doesn't mean "goes to."  It is, as you said, part of .NET's lambda syntax.  In this case `pdf => (stuff)` means that `pdf` is the argument to a method with no name, and the block after the `=>` is the contents of that method.

`Action<T>` is a way to refer to a lambda that takes one argument and doesn't return anything.

Comment: One convention is in fact to pronounce `=>` as "goes to".  So it's not "wrong" to say that, it's simply a matter of understanding what the intended meaning of the phrase "goes to" is.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this method mean run GeneratePdf method then do whatever with
>   the result variable pdf?

Yes. In fact, GeneratePdf can choose not to execute the code at all.

You can think of it as the following:

```
public class MyCode
{
    public void MyAction(FileAttachment pdf)
    {
            var attachInfo = new AttachmentInformation
            {
                AttachmentId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                AttachmentNote = "New Version",
                FileName = pdf.FileName,
                ImageByte = pdf.FileBytes
            };

            try
            {
                /// do something here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ///log error
            }
    }
}


public void GeneratePdf(MyCode onComplete)
{
    string xpsPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + Id + ".xps";

    SaveAsXps(xpsPath, () =>
    {
        string pdfPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + Id + ".pdf";
        string registrationCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("NiXPS:RegistrationCode");
        Converter.Initialize(registrationCode);
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        Converter.XpsToPdf(new MemoryStream(FileToByteArray(xpsPath)), outStream);
        File.Delete(xpsPath);
        byte[] bytes = outStream.ToArray();        
        var attachment = new FileAttachment
        {
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            FileBytes = bytes,
            FileName = fooId + ".pdf"          
        };
        onComplete.MyAction(attachment);
    });
}

public void GenerateCurrentPdf(FooResponse response)
{
    if (response.Success)
    {
        var act = new MyCode();
        GeneratePdf(act);
    }
}
```

This is functionally similar, but there are some subtle differences in the timing of things.

> The GeneratePdf method confused me even more since it's not passing
>   any parameters from the calling method.

It is receiving the `FileAttachment` object from the code inside of `SaveXps`:

```
var attachment = new FileAttachment
{
    ContentType = "application/pdf",
    FileBytes = bytes,
    FileName = fooId + ".pdf"          
};
onComplete(attachment)
```

But keep in mind that you can't say for certain when or if any of the code will be executed. The `SaveXps` method controls the execution within itself by choosing whether to execute the lambda code that is being passed into it, which references and causes the outer lambda code to be executed when `onComplete(attachment)` is reached.